# How to verify that validation labels are in the same range as training labels, Python Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, error-handling, preprocessor, text-classification

As a part of a project I need to train a multilabel text-classifier in Python. I'm following some kind of a guideline for this but because of my low experience in Python I'm having some issues to understand a part of the code that verifies that validation labels are in the same range as training labels. + The reason why this is throwing up an error.

The code that I'm trying to understand is thisone: 
(More specific the 2 first lines from this code are the ones that are confusing to me)

```
num_classes = max(np.array(train_labels)) + 1
missing_classes = [i for i in range(num_classes) if i not in train_labels]
if len(missing_classes):
    raise ValueError('Missing samples with label value(s) '
                     '{missing_classes}. Please make sure you have '
                     'at least one sample for every label value '
                     'in the range(0, {max_class})'.format(
                        missing_classes=missing_classes,
                        max_class=num_classes - 1))

if num_classes <= 1:
    raise ValueError('Invalid number of labels: {num_classes}.'
                     'Please make sure there are at least two classes '
                     'of samples'.format(num_classes=num_classes))

unexpected_labels = [v for v in test_labels if v not in range(num_classes)]
if len(unexpected_labels):
    raise ValueError('Unexpected label values found in the test set:'
                     ' {unexpected_labels}. Please make sure that the '
                     'labels in the validation set are in the same range '
                     'as training labels.'.format(
                         unexpected_labels=unexpected_labels))
```

Also the error that it gives me:

```
    num_classes = max(np.array(train_labels)) 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

In case if this matters for you to know this, the code written before this codeblock is:

```
lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
train_labels = lb.fit_transform(train_df['label'])
train_labels = np.squeeze(train_labels)

print(lb.classes_)

test_labels=lb.transform(test_df['label'])
test_labels=np.squeeze(test_labels)
```

Which gives me this output: 
`[67 68 69 70]`

Any help here to give me a better understanding would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
num_classes = max(np.array(train_labels)) + 1
```

This only makes sense if `train_labels` contains integer values in the range `(0, n_classes)` (Something like `[1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0]` for 4 classes). That doesn't appear to be what you have here...

`lb.classes_ == [67, 68, 69, 70]` means that these were the unique values in `train_df['label']`. The `LabelBinarizer` takes an array of arbitrary labels and "one-hot" encodes them into an array of 0's and 1's with shape `(n_samples, n_classes)`. Something like:

```
>> train_labels
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       ...
       [0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

The maximum value in that array is always `1`, regardless of how many classes there are.

Also, you can only call the built-in `max` function on 1D arrays. The error you got is coming from the fact that `max` tries to compare the values of an iterable, which in the case of a 2D numpy array are row vectors. This is ambiguous, which is why you can't find a maximum value that way:

```
>> np.array([0, 1, 0]) > np.array([1, 0, 0])
array([False,  True,  False])
```

(To actually find the max value of numpy arrays, use `np.max()` instead.)

In any case, if you want the number of classes represented by the binarized label array, you can just get the number of columns:

```
>> train_labels.shape[-1]
4
```

The following line is meant to check that there's at least one instance of each class in `train_labels`, but again it doesn't make sense if `train_labels` is a binary 2D array:

```
missing_classes = [i for i in range(num_classes) if i not in train_labels]
```

You can either convert `train_labels` to an integer label array:

```
>> np.argmax(train_labels, axis=-1)
array([0, 3, ... , 1])
```

Or you can check that there's at least one non-zero value in each column:

```
>> np.sum(train_labels, axis=0) > 0
array([ True,  True,  True,  True])

>> np.all(np.sum(train_labels, axis=0) > 0)
True
```